# Python .pth Files Aren't Working

Tags: python, pythonpath

Directories listed in my .pth configuration file aren't appearing in sys.path.

The contents of configuration file, named `some_code_dirs.pth`:

```
/home/project
```

Paths to the file:

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/some_code_dirs.pth
/usr/lib/python2.6/some_code_dirs.pth
```

Check on sys variables in the python interpreter:

```
>>> print sys.prefix 
'/usr'
>>> print sys.exec_prefix
'/usr'
```

All this seems as required in the Python [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html), but sys.path doesn't include the /home/project directory.

Note that the interpreter *does* add the directory after:

```
>>> site.addsitedir('/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages')
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please include the value of `sys.path`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What OS are you using? On my Ubuntu 9.04 system that directory is not in sys.path.
Try putting it into `/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages`. Notice that it is **dist** instead of **site**.

Comment: Yeah, Ubuntu does some strange and convoluted things with Python's library paths to try to make it fit their packaging system. Very little is in the same place compared to a standard default-compile Python installation. :-(

Comment: That worked -- with the .pth file in dist-packages, /home/project_root shows up in sys.path in the interpreter.

/usr/lib/python2.6 _is_ in sys.path, and a copy of the .pth file is in that directory, so I don't understand why python doesn't pick that up.  I suppose that too is a Ubuntu configuration issue.

I am but an egg, but this seems like a strange set of choices by the Ubuntu folks.

Comment: Well, I don't think that the python interpreter imports .pth files from every path in sys.path.

Answer (score 1):

I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159650/how-to-use-a-custom-site-package-using-pth-files-for-python-2-6) a while ago. Check the encoding of your pth-file. It seems that pth-files are silently ignored if encoded in UTF-8 with BOM.

Comment: That would be understandable, since “UTF-8 with BOM” is bogus and not compatible with ASCII (which is what pth files are)! Odd to see on a linux box though since it is usually only broken Windows apps that produce them.